# Swift: long query in Parse (OR/AND condition)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, parse-platform

I need to do a **[compound query](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-compound-queries)** with Parse SDK.

My code:

```
func retrieveObjects() {
  let conditions: [String] = .....
  let query: PFQuery = self.generateCompoundQueryFromConditions(conditions)
  query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objs:[AnyObject]?,error: NSError?) -> Void in
      NSLog("\(objs)")
  }
}

private func generateCompoundQueryFromConditions(conditions: [String]) -> PFQuery {
    var queries: [PFQuery] = []
    for condition: String in conditions {
        var query = PFQuery(className:"MyClassName")
        query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: condition)
        queries.append(query)
    }
    return PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries(queries)
}
```

Conditions.count -> 24
Code works great, but I get this error:

```
 [Error]: too many $or clauses (Code: 154, Version: 1.7.4)
```

Is there a way to do a query with many OR conditions?

### update

I try also using NSPredicate:

```
private func generateQueryWithPredicateFromConditions(conditions: [String]) -> PFQuery {
    var predicates: [NSPredicate] = []
    for condition in conditions {
        predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "objectId = %@", condition))
    }
    let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate.orPredicateWithSubpredicates(predicates)
    return PFQuery(className: "MyClassName", predicate: predicate)
}
```

Now error is:

```
'This query is too complex. It had an OR with >4 subpredicates after normalization.'
```

So, with N-OR condition, I'm going to do N / 4 + N % 4 PFQuery and then merge results. Could be a solution?

Comment: use "objectId == %@" in predicate.

Comment: no Keybur,  = %@ is ok

Answer (score 1):

I solved by my own in this way, hope can help someone:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "MyClassName")
query.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: conditions)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objs:[AnyObject]?,error: NSError?) -> Void in
    NSLog("\(objs)")
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly and when tested it returned 1k results in under 2 seconds, when searching for 1.5k conditions in a table containing 1.10million records.